# How to add number text files into a PHP math equation?

Tags: php, math, text-files, equation

This is part of script i am putting together earlier. This time I am trying to pull the numbers in the equation from 3 different txt files. Each text file only contains 1 number with no other lines. Example:

```
35
21
3
```

Those are the numbers
However, I don't know how to write the php code to call for the txt files to be used in the code.
I just put an idea of what I am trying to do below. I hope it makes some sense

CODE:

```
 <?php
$filename = 'https://www.justtestdomain.com/results.txt';
$filename = 'https://www.justtestdomain.com/results2.txt';
$filename = 'https://www.justtestdomain.com/results3.txt';
$data = file($filename);
$x= $results;
$y= $results2;
$w= $results3;  

$z=$x-$y-$w;  
echo '<script>var z = ' . $z . ';</script>';  
?>
```

I tried to something similar with JavaScript but it wasn't what I needed. Anyway, is what I am doing possible? Anyway, thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Well that code of course wont work as you will only read the last file you load into `$filename` as you are over writing that variable

Comment: And if you load a value into `$data` using `$data = file($filename);` it has nothing to do with `$results` as you never load that. So take a deep breath and start the code again trying to make it make sense

Comment: Also note that `file — Reads entire file into an array`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not a very good way of getting data to a javascript, this should work.

```
$filename   = 'https://www.justtestdomain.com/results.txt';
$data       = file($filename);
$x          = $data[0];

$filename = 'https://www.justtestdomain.com/results2.txt';
$data       = file($filename);
$y          = $data[0];

$filename = 'https://www.justtestdomain.com/results3.txt';
$data       = file($filename);
$z          = $data[0];

$A = $x - $y - $z;
echo '<script>var z = ' . $A . ';</script>';
```

Comment: yes, the code works riggs! I had to change  $z          = $data[0];  to $w          = $data[0];